# What are the most common words for "to attack"?

Tags: word-choice, words, culture, terminology

The concept of "attacking" is a vary broad one, with a lot of nuance to it. What are the most common/practical words used to describe attacking in Japanese; and what are the nuances to each?

Also, I'm specifically talking about physical attacks; like cutting, stabbing, clawing, punching, smashing, striking, impaling, etc. Not things like fraud, or taunting, or other things that be considered a form of attacking. in some other sense of the word.

Comment: a dictionary might just do the trick. that's what people used to use in the days before the web. or perhaps you could enlighten us why a dictionary won't suffice.

Comment: The problem is that dictionaries don't delve into the nuances of what each word is trying to describe; or give any info as to context, culture, or other nuances.

Comment: i'd suggest reading the example sentences to get a feel for the words. printed dictionaries are much better at filling in those details than the on-line versions currently available.  though i have to say my dictionary that comes with my macbook air is very useful. what nuance are you after?

Comment: Actually... this question sucks; not sure y i asked. plz close, unsure... :(

Comment: Without context, I don't think I can do a job better than a dictionary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i want to share my opinion about your question.
there are a lot of words refer to attack but, ill explain some.

First ill share verbs that refer to attack.

> 切る   （きる）    **Cutting**. (but its refer to general cutting.)
>   刺す   （さす）    **Stabbing**, Impaling, Pierce, etc. 
>   引っ掻く （ひっかく） **Clawing**. 
>   殴る   （なぐる）   **Punching**, Hit. 
>   撃つ   （うつ）    **Shoot (gun,Cannon,etc)**, Defeat, Destroy, etc. 
>   打つ   （うつ）    **Striking**, Smashing, Punching, Slap, etc.

**Im not sure its right or wrong, but i try to help and thats what i get for studying japanese. 

Feel free to correct me.**

Comment: You're missing at least three [襲]{おそ}う, [叩]{たた}く, [攻]{せ}める

Comment: ^ 攻撃する is also common. You'd also use 暴力をふるう depending on context.

Comment: ^^ yeah there plenty words refer to attack but, he want specific answer so i just share my daily uses to answer his questions.

Comment: `my daily uses`. What exactly do you during a day?

Comment: ^ 私も思いましたwww --